# Why Doesn't G++ Warn About Unused Result of Const Member?

Tags: c++, g++, compiler-warnings

I am very much annoyed about a stupid mistake that I have made. But I am even annoyed more about my compiler (g++ 8.1) that didn't warn me. ;-)

Please consider the following code:

```
class Test
{
public:

    int getNumber() const
    {
        return 3;
    }
};

int main(void)
{
    Test test;
    test.getNumber();

    return 0;
}
```

In my opinion the line

```
test.getNumber();
```

is definitely wrong. A const member of `Test` is called, but the return value is not used. Even though I have been compiling with `-Wall -Wextra` g++ refused to issue a warning. I have checked the documentation of `-Wunused-result`. If I add the attribute `__attribute__ ((warn_unused_result))` to the member, then the compiler will indeed warn me.

But why is this necessary? Isn't ignoring the return value of a const method always wrong? And shouldn't I have the possibility to set the `warn_unused_result` attribute automatically for all const members?

I am very much excited about your answers.

Comment: In short: `const` functions are not necessarily pure functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No not in full generality.

1. There could be `mutable` members in the class. Granted the compiler could check that.
2. The `const` method might have other side effects (writing to the console for example), which would be difficult to detect if the function implementation was in a different translation unit.

Comment: Also relevant: [`[[nodiscard]]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/nodiscard).

Comment: @Deduplicator, what do you mean with that?

Comment: @BenjaminBihler If you are sure that your function is being used incorrectly if the return value is discarded, you can add the `[[nodiscard]]` attribute (since C++14). The compiler must then complain in said case.

Comment: @Max Langhof But you seem to be wrong about the standard. According to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/nodiscard it has been introduced with C++17.

Comment: @BenjaminBihler Oops, you're right. C++17 indeed. It's also "is encouraged to complain (warn)", not "must complain".